# add multiple webkit-gradient for every side

Tags: html, css, webkit, transparency

So i have this css code:

```
img {
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 65%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))
}
```

It makes the bottom of my img fade in the background, with transparency. However, i want to do this on each side. Is there a way to do that

Thanks for your help

Comment: A bigger chunk of your source code and some more details would be helpful.

Comment: @Zero i edited, i hope this is enough. My English is terrible, so it's hard to explain. If it is still not clear, i'll make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this only works in Chrome and perhaps Safari, but you can do something like the following:

```
img{
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0))), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,1)));
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
}
```

This uses two (comma-separated) gradients that have multiple `color-stop()`s instead of just `from()` and `to()`.  I don't exactly know why it works that the combination of `-webkit-mask-composite: source-out` with the second gradient using opposite opacity values in the 2nd gradient. I just happened to notice that it does while playing with different values of `-webkit-mask-composite`.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esz0vLcu/)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i spend like 3 hours looking for this. Thanks for your help